# "system." In a Collection Name in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I just discovered a bizarre behavior exhibited by MongoDB.

Apparently, any collection name with the string "system." anywhere in it will just not function correctly.

To make matters worse, it won't even tell you anything is wrong!

It's really more a matter of curiosity, but does anybody have any idea why this would happen?  Is it documented somewhere?

My assumption is that it uses ""system.*" collections to store things internally (like indexes) and doesn't want you messing with them, but this doesn't seem like the correct behavior to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct "system.*" is a reserved collection namespace used by MongoDB in each DB.

It is used to store indexes and users, etc.

*SQL Server has many such tables too, and I don't believe they warn you not to use them either :)*

But you could always put in a request for such functionality: http://jira.mongodb.org/

You can see them by running ...

`> show collections`

and you'll see something like ...

`system.indexes`

`system.users`

So, you can see your indexes for example:

`> db.system.indexes.find()`

From the MongoDB docs:

> The **.system.*** namespaces in
>   MongoDB are special and contain
>   database system information.  System
>   collections include:
>
> - **system.namespaces** lists all namespaces.
> - **system.indexes** lists all indexes.
> - Additional namespace / index metadata exists in the database.ns
>     files, and is opaque.
> - **system.profile** stores database profiling information.
> - **system.users** lists users who may access the database.
> - **local.sources** stores replica slave configuration data and state.
> - Information on the structure of a stored object is stored within the
>     object itself.  See BSON .
>
> There are several restrictions on
>   manipulation of objects in the system
>   collections. Inserting in
>   system.indexes adds an index, but
>   otherwise that table is immutable (the
>   special drop index command updates it
>   for you). **system.users** is modifiable. 
>   **system.profile** is droppable.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/

Comment: Is it possible to get the records from every collections like if i have user.primary and user.secondary in that collections can i select user by name from both collection at a single time?